# Prove the statement: $\forall x \; \exists y \; (x+y)^2 \gt x^2 + y^2$. Universe of discourse is the natural numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The following is my solution, but I am not sure if it is sufficient as a proof.
I don't know how to use the coding language in stack exchange, but basically the statement is:
For all x in N, there exists y in N such that (x+y)^2 > x^2 + y^2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdx0L.png)

Comment: The proof there is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your input.

Comment: Why not choose $y=1$?

Comment: Do you know that $(x+y)^2=x^?+y^2+2xy$ ?

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, but I just felt it would be nicer to generalize it a bit and so came up with this.

Comment: Thus, $(x+y)^2 > x^2+y^2$ amounts to $2xy > 0$. Thus : $\forall x \exists y (2xy > 0)$ holds in $\mathbb N$ ?

Comment: [Is $0 \in \mathbb N$ ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) If so, what about $2(0y) > 0$ ?

Comment: 0 is not an element of natural numbers. And yes, I am aware what the expansion is. I know an alternative way of doing this, but I just wanted to know if doing it this way would also be valid.

Comment: @mightywar, some conventions *do* include $0$ as a natural number, so it doesn't hurt to be crystal clear by saying "positive integers" instead of "natural numbers."

Comment: Oh, really? I didn't know that. But in the coursework I am doing, it does not include 0 in the natural numbers, hence why I said it with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just take $y=x$. For all $x \in \mathbb{N}^*$, you have 
$$(x+x)^2 = 4x^2 > 2x^2 = x^2 + x^2$$